# Finding the Image of a Complex Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

I want to find the image of the complex transformation $f(z)=w=2z+\frac{1}{z}$ on the exterior of the unit circle in the complex plane. This is clearly a conformal mapping except at the points $z=0$ where the function has a pole and at the points $z=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ where $f'(z)=0$. So we can make use of the fact that we know for conformal mappings: $\partial f(D)=f(\partial D)$.

Hence, we should just have to find the image of the boundary and a single point. To do this, I started by noting that:
$$ \partial D = \{z=e^{i\theta}:0\leq\theta<2\pi\} $$
I then found the real and imaginary parts of the function $f(z)=w=u+iv$:
$$ w = 2z+\frac{1}{z} = 2x+i2y+\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2} = (2x+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}) + i(2y - \frac{y}{x^2+y^2})=u+iv $$
However, here is where I'm starting to confuse myself. On the boundary of $D$, we know that $x^2+y^2=r^2=1$ and we can convert our cartesian coordinate to polar, so we have:
$$ w = u+iv = (3x)+i(y) = (3\cos(\theta))+i(\sin(\theta)) $$
Then it follows that $-3\leq u\leq3$ and $-1\leq v\leq1$. But aren't Joukowski transformations supposed to map the exterior of circles to the exterior of an ellipse? Am I missing something or oversimplifying somewhere?

Comment: "*Then it follows that $-3\leq u\leq3$ and $-1\leq v\leq1$*" $\;-\;$ That's a necessary condition, but not a sufficient (or equivalent) one.  If, instead, you eliminate $\theta$ between $u,v$ you get the actual ellipse $(u/3)^2+v^2=1$.

Comment: The final equation is the parametric form of an ellipse. As @dxiv points out you can eliminate $\theta$ to put it into quadradic form.

Comment: I think I see what you mean - so starting with $\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)=1$, I can then just use the fact that $\cos^2(\theta) = (\frac{u}{3})^2$ and $\sin^2(\theta)=v^2$ from my two equations to then get $(u/3)^2+v^2=1$